# Literature On Simple Type Theory

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, type-theory, intuitionistic-logic

I am wondering where I can find literature describing the rules for a simple type theory with just products, sums, function types, unit and the empty type. Robert Harper describes such a theory 3 minutes in to this YouTube video:

[Robert Harper's Type Theory Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHteAK7GSRY&list=PLt7hcIEdZLAnbUxKaG7XIynEWrozOBtXU&index=6)

He says such a type theory corresponds to intuitionistic propositional logic, as well as to the theory of a free bicartesian closed category. Harper does not go over all the details , and I would appreciate some literature covering all the inference rules etc. Ideally using the notation with $\vdash$ and horizontal lines. This is the same notation used in

[function type in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+type)

Any literature exhaustively covering the rules behind a type theory with products and function objects would be appreciated.

Comment: One reference for the inference rules is Balat–Cosmo–Fiore's [Extensional Normalisation and Type-Directed Partial Evaluation for Typed Lambda Calculus with Sums](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mpf23/papers/Types/tdpe.pdf) (page 3).

Comment: That looks really useful. But I would still really like to see the rules for the formation of a context $\Gamma.$

Comment: Pierce's [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) is a standard reference for introductions to type theory, but many university courses on type theory (e.g. [this one](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~pbl/mgs/lam/) by Levy) will cover this.